# Error consulta ORA-00937: la función de grupo no es de grupo único ORACLE PL-SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-12c

```
SELECT
COUNT(ID_LUGE_MPIO),
SUM (TCOUNT.FAMILIAS),
COUNT (TCOUNT.ORD_JUEZ),
(SELECT COUNT (CIUDAD) FROM RTI_ETNICAS WHERE CIUDAD = '8303' GROUP BY 
CIUDAD),
SUM (TCOUNT.HECTAREAS)
FROM 
RTI_FALLOS TCOUNT

WHERE
TCOUNT.ID_LUGE_MPIO = '8303'
;
```

Tengo la anterior consulta, el select interno me genera la consulta pero al ejecutar todo obtengo ORA-00937: la función de grupo no es de grupo único, agradezco su colaboración.

Comment: Prueba reemplazar esto `(SELECT COUNT (CIUDAD) FROM RTI_ETNICAS WHERE CIUDAD = '8303' GROUP BY CIUDAD)` por esto: `(SELECT COUNT (CIUDAD) FROM RTI_ETNICAS WHERE CIUDAD = '8303')`